# EditText displays text slightly off?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I am using and EditText to display my app's EULA. The EditText is marked singleLine=false and enabled = false.

When I ev.setText='....', the text appears slightly shifted 1 and 1/2 characters to the left plus down 1 and 1/2 lines. That is, the text is not registered/displayed properly to the top left corner. Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the XML and some code?

Answer (score 0):

Why an EditText?  Seems like a TextView would be the more proper vehicle to display that.

As for the text position, it sounds like you have padding (or margins, or both) specified in the XML.

Comment: The XML is:   <EditText 
      android:id="@+id/etLoginEula"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:singleLine="false"
   android:minLines="10"
   android:maxLines="10"
   android:enabled="false"
   android:clickable="false"
   android:visibility="gone" 
   android:gravity="top"
   android:textColor="#000000"
      />

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
myEtLoginEula.setEnabled(false);        
myEtLoginEula.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
myEtLoginEula.setText(myJS.getString("EULAText").replace("<br>","\n") + "\n");
myEtLoginEula.setScroller(new Scroller(getBaseContext()));    
myEtLoginEula.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);  
myEtLoginEula.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

I was previously setting the text, `.setText(myJS...)` **after** the `.setMovementMethod`. It does not like that. I had originally obtained all this months back from another SO question regarding scrolling. Seems to work now. I will revisit `TextView`instead of `EditText`as well. Thanks for your patience as I am newbie to SO responding!